# Some threads does not execute after creating on Multi-threaded app

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I've currently developing a program which executes some AT commands periodically.
I tried to make it multi-threaded because this program should work with 8 GSM modems concurrently.
here is my extended TThread class as TWorkerThread:

```
TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
private
  FThreadJob       : TThreadJobs;
  FSimNum          : Word;
  FZylGSM          : TZylGSM;
  SL_AT            : TStringList;
  FSignalGauge     : TsGauge;
  procedure SyncProc;

public
  TerminateThread   : Boolean;
  constructor Create;
  property ThreadJob  : TThreadJobs read FThreadJob write FThreadJob;
  property ZylGSM     : TZylGSM read FZylGSM write FZylGSM;
  property SimNum     : Word read FSimNum write FSimNum;
  property SignalGauge: TsGauge read FSignalGauge write FSignalGauge;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
end;
```

And body of my thread's methods :

```
    constructor TWorkerThread.Create;
    begin
      inherited Create(True);
      if Not Assigned(SL_AT) then SL_AT := TStringList.Create;
      SL_AT.Clear;
      FThreadJob := tjNone;
      TerminateThread := False;
      FreeOnTerminate := True;
    end;



    procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
    begin
      inherited;
      if FThreadJob = tjNone then Exit;
      while TerminateThread=False do Synchronize(SyncProc);
    end;




    procedure TWorkerThread.SyncProc;
    var
      ts : String;
      SignalStrength : Byte;
    begin
      if bTerminateFlag then TerminateThread := True;
      if TerminateThread then Exit;
      case FThreadJob of
        tjOperatorName  : ;

        tjSignalQuality :
          begin
            FZylGSM.ExecuteATCommand('AT+CSQ', SL_AT);
            if (SL_AT.Count>2) And (Pos('OK', SL_AT[2])>0) then begin
              ts := Copy(SL_AT[1], Pos(':', SL_AT[1])+1, Length(SL_AT[1]));
              ts := Trim(ts);
              if ts = '99' then ts:='0';
              SignalStrength := StrToIntDef(ts, 0);
              SignalGauge.Progress := SignalStrength;
            end;
            if bTerminateFlag then TerminateThread := True;
    //        Application.ProcessMessages;
          end;
      end;
    end;
```

I've used a for loop to create 8 threads like this:

```
DevPorts.GSM_Ports[i].WorkerThread := TWorkerThread.Create;
DevPorts.GSM_Ports[i].WorkerThread.ThreadJob := tjSignalQuality;
DevPorts.GSM_Ports[i].WorkerThread.SimNum := i+1;
DevPorts.GSM_Ports[i].WorkerThread.SignalGauge := FindComponent('Sig_'+IntToStr(i)) as TsGauge;
DevPorts.GSM_Ports[i].WorkerThread.ZylGSM := DevPorts.GSM_Ports[i].Comm;
DevPorts.GSM_Ports[i].WorkerThread.Start;
```

The program worked as expected when I commented "Application.ProcessMessages", the problem is when I use "Application.ProcessMessages" in "TWorkerThread.SyncProc", some of my threads don't executes. I know it could be wrong to use ProcessMessage in the thread function but I did it because the Main GUI thread hangs up during send/recv of threads.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your entries design is bogus. All the work is performed in the main thread. Remove all the threading code and do the work in the main thread. Or use threads and do the work in the threads. And yes ProcessMessages is a bad idea. Don't use it ever.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for your comment. As I mentioned I have to do send/recv to each GSM modem concurrently. so, I can't do all the works in the main thread.  Can you please let me know why all the works perform in the main thread in my codes?

Comment: Because of your use of Synchronize. There are so many things wrong with your code. Stack Overflow isn't really about debugging individuals code. It's about general questions and answers that can be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `Application.ProcessMessages` from your threads. This is a terrible thing to do. The best you can hope for is spectacular failures. It calls code that should be run on the main thread on ***the wrong threads***.

The reason your main GUI thread hangs is because you're ***not*** running anything multi-threaded. The line `while TerminateThread=False do Synchronize(SyncProc);` is synchronising everything to run back on the main thread. So currently your threads are pointless.

The purpose of `Synchronize()` is to allow threads to coordinate access to ***shared*** data so you don't have to deal with race conditions. However, the *ideal* is to share as ***little data as possible*** so that your threads can work independently of each other (and the main thread), without having to worry values under its control being changed at inappropriate times.

So alarm bells are screaming when you make most of your worker thread's members public:

```
public
  TerminateThread   : Boolean;
  constructor Create;
  property ThreadJob  : TThreadJobs read FThreadJob write FThreadJob;
  property ZylGSM     : TZylGSM read FZylGSM write FZylGSM;
  property SimNum     : Word read FSimNum write FSimNum;
  property SignalGauge: TsGauge read FSignalGauge write FSignalGauge;
```

You need to reevaluate what the responsibilities of your worker threads are and encapsulate that work appropriately. (***Only call `Synchronize()` for code that should be synchronised!***) However, I'm not familiar with the components you're using, and you may find that they're poorly written and not suitable for multi-threading as a result.

## Other problems

Apart from the glaring immediate problems you have. There are also a number of mistakes demonstrating gaps in your understanding of multi-threaded development.

- Do not call `inherited` from `TWorkerThread.Execute`. The ancestor method is abstract - has no implementation an cannot be called. And even though the Delphi compiler generously protects you from your mistake, it's a mistake nonetheless.
- Your implementation of `TerminateThread : Boolean;` replicates existing functionality built into `TThread`. Instead of reinventing the wheel, use what Delphi has already provided.
- I cannot see where you declared or are setting `bTerminateFlag`. My hunch is it's global. Using globals with multiple threads is like juggling flaming torches while standing in a room filled with open barrels of gunpowder.

## Some guesses

I can hazard some guesses based on what you are trying to do in the code you have shown.

- It looks like you're updating `TsGuage` instances to visually indicate the signal strength for each device. This is a GUI update that must be synchronised.
- The line `FZylGSM.ExecuteATCommand('AT+CSQ', SL_AT);` seems to be the place where you interact with the device. It's probably also the slowest and what you want to processes off the main thread. This should not be synchronised if possible. *However, it as indicated earlier, the feasibility of doing so depends on the implementation of that component.*
- That said, it seems the only line you should be synchronising is: `SignalGauge.Progress := SignalStrength;`.

Comment: ProcessMessages is called here from the main thread. What happens next is a long running comment trail where asker changes code as you suggest and asks why it doesn't work. Good luck with that.

Comment: @Craig  Many thanks for your comment and your time.  you're completely right. FZylGSM.ExecuteAtCommand is the slowest and that's why I tried to make the program multi-threaded. I keep in my mind your suggestions and really appreciate your time for analyzing my poor code.